# Cleaner / Multiple -notlike in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to filter out some junk on a simple where-object of services but the -notlike is going to get long, I've tried but can't get it working but is there a way to remove the duplicate -notlike into one for example -notlike 'Softw*','Applic*','this*','that*'

```
Where-Object { $_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' -and $_.State -ne 'Running' -and $_.Displayname -notlike '*.NET*' -and $_.Displayname -notlike 'Softw*'-and $_.Displayname -notlike 'Applic*'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use -notmatch:

```
$_.Displayname -notmatch "(\.NET|Softw|Applic)"
```

Comment: Are you sure about your regex?